# Word VBA macro to bold part of all instances of a specific text string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using the following code to bold parts of a text string, in this case where the word 'Fish' is in brackets after the word 'Oil':

```
Sub ReplaceAndFormat16()
Dim sConst1 As String, sReplaceMent As String
Dim rRange As Range, rFormat As Range
sConst1 = "Fish"
sReplaceMent = "Oil (" & sConst1 & ")"
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
   .Text = "Oil (Fish)"
    .Replacement.Text = sReplaceMent
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    If .Found Then
        Set rRange = Selection.Range
       Set rFormat = ActiveDocument.Range(rRange.Start + 5, rRange.Start + 5 + VBA.Len(sConst1))
       rFormat.Font.Bold = True
   End If
   End With
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly, but only bolds the first instance, and my documents may have up to four instances of this phrase that need to be formatted bold.
How do I amend the code so it carries on and bolds all instances in the document? I am very new to VBA, so apologies if this seems like a stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

`.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne`

to

```
.execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Edit

OK the above was a stupid response.  The code below does the right thing

```
Sub ReplaceAndFormat16()
Const myFindStr                      As String = "Oil (Fish)"
Dim myFindRange                      As Word.Range

    Set myFindRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)

    Do
        With myFindRange.Find

            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = myFindStr
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False 
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute

            If .Found Then
                With myFindRange
                    .MoveStartUntil cset:="fF"
                    .MoveEndUntil cset:="hH", Count:=wdBackward
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                End With
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If

        End With

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this Steven - unfortunately this change stops the macro working at all. Maybe there are other changes required?

Comment: You are quite right.  I hang my head in shame.  I've revised my answer with code that does what you wish.

Comment: Hi Steven, Much appreciated, this does indeed perform the multiple bolding, but then goes into an endless loop afterwards and crashes Word eventually. Is there a way of limiting how many instances the code looks for?

Comment: Hi Alison.  My Bad.  Change wdFindContinue to wdFindStop and all should be OK.